# Bulk loading data from json files to janusgraph example

Tags: tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I am looking for a complete example for bulk loading data into janusgraph using tinkerpop3's hadoop-gremlin package. I read the documentation and didn't find any complete example, only fragments of code and suggestions.

Comment: Can you elaborate where you are trying to bulk upload? HBase or Cassandra?

Comment: We are using Janusgraph with cassandra backend. Most of our data is produced from Spark jobs. The best case solution for us would be to be able to load data into janusgraph with a spark job. Currently, we are using normal java api to load data with multiple threads and batch mode set to true.